# Sass doesn't compile variables properly

Tags: sass

I start to write my own SCSS along with `boostrap`. I follow the hierarchy of the framework like:

```
/* The main file and all partial files are in the same directory */
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";

@import "other-components";
```

Everything compiles perfectly except that every variable from `variables.scss` is not compiled. From my understanding, CSS doesn't have variables except for `:root`, so SCSS variables will be compiled directly to its value in CSS. But when it's done compiling, the variables in CSS remain the same as they're in SCSS, just name like `--primary` but not value like `#000`.

Before my post gets slammed as duplicate, here's what I've done:

1. I've followed Bootstrap's practice. You can check them on Github.
2. I use VSCode and my colors have boxes right next to them, so I've written valid hex values;
3. I've tried to switch to `@use` and use as namespace instead of `@import`.
4. I've tried to rename my `variables` file with and without underscore `_` back and forth. It doesn't help solve the problems.
5. The compiler shows no error whatsoever.
6. I only use `sass` package to compile `.scss` to `.css`. No extra libraries.

[main.scss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB8ic.png)

[_variables.scss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leZp0.png)

[main.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIXug.png)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: When using CSS variables, use the #{} to insert sass code into them. So ‘—variable: #{$sass-var};

Comment: @somethinghere this is the solution, please post it as such

Comment: @Theo Okay then, will do. Forgot I ever commented here :D

Answer (score 7):

When using standard CSS variables, you should make SASS write out the contents like this:

```
--variable: #{$sass-var};
```

Otherwise SASS will print the variable as if it's a valid value inside a CSS value (since you could technically define something like `--var: $text` and then use it later with `content: var(--var)` to print out that string). Anyways, it's because SASS otherwise doesn't know if you want to print the output of the variable, or just a string named similar to a sass variable.